# Measurability issue in the definition of maximal singular integral operator

Tags: harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

I'm learning harmonic analysis with Grafakos' book *Classical Fourier Analysis*. I'm having a problem understanding the definition 5.2.1 of maximal singular integral operators.

Let me recall the definition. Here, $\Omega \colon \mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an integrable function with mean $0$. For $0 < \epsilon < N$ and $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (for $1 \leq p < \infty$), we define the truncated singular integral
$$ T^{(\varepsilon, N)} f(x) = \int_{\varepsilon \leq |y| \leq N} \frac{\Omega(y/|y|)}{|y|^n} f(x - y) \mathrm{d}y$$
This quantity is defined for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, as one can easily prove that $\|T^{(\varepsilon, N)} f\|_p < \infty$. But as I understand it, the negligible set of points at which the above quantity is not defined depends on $\varepsilon$ and $N$. Therefore, I don't know how to make sense of the maximal singular operator
$$
T^{(*,*)}f(x) = \sup_{\varepsilon, N} |T^{(\varepsilon, N)}f(x)|
$$
Am I missing something?

Note that my concerns disappear in the case $\Omega$ is bounded, as in that case, $T^{(\varepsilon, N)}$ is defined for all $f$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: To do this properly, you should define the maximal operator not as pointwise supremum, but as supremum in the Banach lattice $L^p$. I give more details and a reference in the linked question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145178/measurability-of-maximal-functions?rq=1.

Comment: @MaoWao this could fix the problem but I believe there are more details to work out. If I understand correctly, to make sense of the supremum, I need to prove that the family of functions $T^{(\varepsilon, N)}f$ is order-bounded in $L^p$...

Comment: Since you work with non-negative functions, you can define the lattice supremum in the space of equivalence classes of $[0,\infty]$-valued measurable functions.